# Yandex API для Android

Tags: java, android, yandex-maps-api

В Yandex API для Android нашли баг. Когда ставим много pointer-ев на карте, то некоторые из них перекрывают всплывающий popup. Можно ли как нибудь поднять popup над всеми pointer-ами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Обновление:** Вот код, который сразу отрисовывает point и сразу popup:

```
 private void showOnMap(ArrayList<Geolocation> geolocations) {
        geolocationForList.clear();
        geolocationForList.addAll(geolocations);
        overlay.clearOverlayItems();
        if (geolocations.size() != 0) {
//            draw each advert element on the map
            for (Geolocation o : geolocations) {
                GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(o.getLatitude(), o.getLongitude());
                OverlayItem item = new OverlayItem(p, baseActivity.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.advert_marker_1));
                if(o.getAdverts().size() == 1)
                    realtyTypeStr = realtyType[o.getAdverts().get(0).getBuildType()];
                BalloonItemSearch balloonItem = new BalloonItemSearch(realtyTypeStr, baseActivity, item.getGeoPoint(), o);

                balloonItem.setObject();
                balloonItem.setOnBalloonListener(balloonItem);
                item.setBalloonItem(balloonItem);
                balloonItem.setOnViewClickListener();
                balloonItem.setPresenter(this);
                overlay.addOverlayItem(item);
            }
        }
        mOverlayManager.addOverlay(overlay);
        stopDrawing();
        repaintMap();
    }
```

Как сделать так, чтобы сначала отрисовались pointer-ы, а лишь потом popup-ы?

Answer (score 3):

Это называется не popup, а сниппет и бага сдесь нет. В map Api есть возможность показывать только один сниппет одновременно.

Comment: ну да.... но если pointer-ев на карте много.... то некоторые другие pointer-ы закрывают этот сниппет

Comment: можете прикрепить скрин к вопросу, а то после вашего коммента ничего не понятно ?

Comment: прикрепил скрин

Comment: для меток нужно бы сделать кластеризацию, а то они у вас очень уж близко друг к дружке) а насчёт того, что на ваш сниппет  налазят метки     вы можете при отрисовке карты сначала вывести метки, а после показать нужный сниппет.

Comment: сниппет появляется после, того как кликнешь на pointer. Есть ли возможность в Yandex API... при клике на pointer вытащить наверх и pointer и сниппет?

Comment: я обновил вопрос...